# TypeError: AuthenticationMiddleware.__call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client_name'

Tags: django-models, jinja2

TypeError: AuthenticationMiddleware.**call**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client_name'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYIXN.png)

I want to save accept or reject status in one of my models but got this error, I am not able to solve even after making changes in middleware

Comment: Share your middleware, use code, not images of code.

Comment: Thank you bud, But my problem is solved. Thanks for consideration.